# Does string change const char * when used as parameter

Tags: c++, string

Curious as to the reason the constructor string (const char* s), sometimes alters the characters in const char *. I have a simple method that checks if a flag is set alters the string in some way searches a tree and return a value. It seems to work fine if I only use strings; however for some odd reason when I use const char * received from another function as a parameter into the function the const char * I recieve back is sometimes returned incomplete. Which is the cause for subtle errors I was unable to locate until recently. It seems to work if inside the method I create another string and append the string parameter to the new string but this seems like the wrong way to resolve this issue. I believe it could be a misunderstanding of the proper use of the constructor, Does anyone have any insight into this subtle issue?

As a simple example the terminal returns the below result, Note the symbol for an incomplete character did not copy correctly and instead is blank.

[image]

**EDIT:**
@T.C.
I in no way blame the string class T.C., I'm well aware that it is my error and I am attempting to understand the issue. It is most probably a misinterpretation on the use of the constructors in the std::string class. A bit of back story I am using C/C++ and java together for practice. I created a class that seemed to pass minimal testing in C++ and created a wrapper so that I can use it in C. When I pass a string as a parameter instead of const char * it works without a problem; however to the best of my understanding std::string should copy the characters though this I am not sure. I'm aware that a people will tell me to only use C++ and not to mix the two like in the answers to other questions when individuals mix the two but any direction would be appreciated.

I wanted to make the question short originally but posted before adding the code. Attached is a snippet of its use and a proper picture of the missing character symbol I could not find earlier.

LZW.c (C Class)

```
...
const char * tex = Trie_Int_longestPrefix(trie,input); //Find max prefix match tex
printf("%25s\t",tex);
//FOR SOME REASON TEX CHANGES AFTER THIS CALL
arr[size++] = Trie_Int_get(trie,tex);   //Add encoding 
printf("%25s\n",tex);
int t = strlen(tex);
...
```

ctrie.cpp (C-Wrapper Class)

```
...
//Return Value
int Trie_Int_get(Trie_Int * t,const char * key){return ((Trie<int> *)t)->get(key); }
...
//Find and return longest prefix of s in TST
const char * Trie_Int_longestPrefix(Trie_Int * t,const char * s){return  ((Trie<int> *)t)->longestPrefix(s).c_str();}
...
```

Trie.ii (C++ Class)

```
...
template<typename value>
value Trie<value>::get(std::string key,const bool & ignoreCase) const {
    if(key.empty()){throw std::invalid_argument("key must have length >= 1");}
    if(ignoreCase)__toLowerCase(key);
    TrieNode* x = get(root,key,0,ignoreCase);
    return x!=nullptr? x->val : defVal;
}
template<typename value>
std::string Trie<value>::longestPrefix(std::string key,const bool & ignoreCase) const{
...Kind of Long
}
...
```

Comment: Probably has nothing to do with `string` and everything to do with other parts of your code.

Comment: Please post the code that exhibits the problem.

Comment: You have a bug in your code.  You'll have to post a small, self-contained example that reproduces the problem if you'd like help identifying the bug.

Comment: one of the things about code is that… you know, it’s code, you don’t have to describe it, you can show the actual code. Post a small, self-contained example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @T.C. I never stated it was a problem with the string class that would be a bit obnoxious to assume the issue was any one else fault but my own

Comment: I am aware that it is seldom the issue of the stl and usually an issue of the programmer. In my question I intended to ask for assistance in its proper use and where it is possible that I made a mistake in assumption.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
template<typename value>
std::string Trie<value>::longestPrefix(
    std::string key,const bool & ignoreCase) const;

//Find and return longest prefix of s in TST
const char * Trie_Int_longestPrefix(Trie_Int * t,const char * s)
{return  ((Trie<int> *)t)->longestPrefix(s).c_str();}
```

When a function returns a class type (directly, not a reference to type), calling that function creates a temporary class object which lives until the end of the full-expression that calls it.  (The most common kind of "full-expression" is, like in this case, a statement.)

`std::string::c_str()` returns a C string pointer which is guaranteed to be valid until any non-const member of the `string` is called, including the destructor.

So that `Trie_Int_longestPrefix` function returns a pointer which is already invalid, and any use of it counts as undefined behavior.

In your test run, the memory the invalid pointer pointed at just happened to still contain some "expected" data the first time you print it.  But by the second time, some other code has apparently reused that region of memory for something else.

Comment: Ah I see, Thank you. I originally was confused as to why c_str() worked at all after I left the method; So originally tried using a struct but reverted to simply allocating space for it, after I fixed another issue deciding that both methods seemed a bit messy and since I never saw a difference when I checked the values I assumed that it was okay. I suppose I will simple have to allocate memory and remember to delete it outside of the function.